# stl pairs and binary search

Tags: c++, stl

I want to make a dictionary program and my dictionary is implemented with pairs. I want to search in my array for a term and return a description all of this using stl function. I made this:

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<fstream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

bool compare(pair<string,string>a,pair<string,string>b) {
    return a.first<b.first;
}

int main() {
    pair<string,string> a[100]=pair<string,string>();
    int dimension=0;
    ifstream f("dictionar.in");
    string name,description;
    while(f>>name) {
        getline(f,description);
        a[dimension]=make_pair(name,description);
        dimension++;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<dimension;i++)
        cout<<a[i].first<<" "<<a[i].second<<endl;

    sort(a,a+dimension,compare);
    cout<<endl;

    for(int i=0;i<dimension;i++)
        cout<<a[i].first<<" "<<a[i].second<<endl;
    string searchelem;

    cin>>searchelem;
}
```

I want to use 'searchelement' to find if in the pair array there is an element equal with searchelement and if there is return the index. What function should i use?

Comment: Use `std::map`.  It was designed for dictionary usage.  The `std::map` also uses `std::pair`.

Comment: For God's sake use `typedef`

Comment: @Slava For $DEITY's sake, use `using` ;)

Comment: @JesperJuhl whatever way, but avoid code duplicate

Comment: what Slava wanted to say?

Comment: @user6575913 Slava wanted to say that creating type alias for `std::pair<std::string,std::string>` not only makes your code easier to change but also easier to read.

Comment: As for your question you can use `std::lower_bound` but it is unclear why you want to reimplement `std::map`

Comment: a problem ask me to do so and i want to do it:))

Comment: and there is yet [std::binary_search](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/) - requires the range of the iterators being sorted, but you did so already, so fine...

Comment: but binary_search just return true or false not the index or the element. I want the element because the problems says in most efficient way using stl function and pairs. I found a method using find_if but i don't know if it is efficient

Comment: @user6575913 `std::find` in this case is definatly less efficient as it does linear search.

Comment: but is there a method that doesn't take O(N) where n is the number of key?(i am referring to pairs and methods associated with pairs in STL not map)

Comment: @user6575913 Yes there is a method and I have already provided it for you in my answer. Can you read it?

Comment: but the method it is correct? i can't see a call to that function like this? are you not missed an element or mismatch compare with value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `std::map`.  A map is often referred to as an *associated array* or *dictionary*.

You may want to break up the key and values and use a *trie* data structure.  The *trie* allows for a more efficient lookup (by word length).

Comment: but it can be done with pairs? or i have to split like you say?

Comment: Sure you *could* implement a solution with `pair`, but it's most likely to be more code, less readable and slower than just doing the straight-forward thing and use a `map`.

Comment: and then when i use pairs and when i use map? or which one of this is better?

Comment: A `std::map` uses `std::pair`.  The map data structure is designed for fast lookups with [key, value] pairs.  Many of the `std::map` interfaces hide the underlying `std::pair` data structure.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement binary search using `std::equal_range`:

```
string searchelem;
cin>>searchelem;
auto p = std::equal_range( a,a+dimension,compare);
if( p.first == p.second ) {
    // not found
else
    std::cout << "for " << searchelem << " found " << p.first->second << std::endl;
```

you can use `std::lower_bound` as well, but then you need to check if key is equal, as it returns first element which is not less than key.

Your code though may have issue (unlike `std::map`) - it keeps duplicates if they happen to be in the file. You may remove them using `std::remove_if` but it is simpler and cleaner just to use `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`